# What conditions must be imposed on an atlas, when given in an "internal" way, to guarantee that it forms a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

An atlas can be defined as a set of $\{U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha\}$, where $U_\alpha \subseteq S$ are subsets of a topologically suitable set $S$ and $\phi_\alpha : U_\alpha \rightarrow V_\alpha \subseteq\mathbb R^n$ are invertible functions that give coordinates to the subsets. Sometimes, it can be useful to take an "internal" view, where we forget that the points in $S$ belong to a larger space in order to focus on what things look like "inside" the manifold. In practice, I have seen "inside view atlases" given in forms like, $(\{V_\alpha\ \subseteq R^n\},\{\varphi_{\alpha\beta} : U_\alpha \subseteq V_\alpha \rightarrow U_\beta \subseteq V_\beta\})$: a set of subsets of Euclidian space, along with the connecting functions $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}$ that link them all together. It's easy to go from the first view to the second view, because it is clear that $\varphi_{\alpha\beta} = \phi_\beta \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}$ will work. However, after thinking about it, I have realized that it is not so clear that you can always go in the other direction.

In the second way of writing atlases, it is possible to have contradictions. The way I have written it, it would be permitted that $\varphi_{12}\varphi_{21}x\neq x$, although it is easy to prevent this by adding a condition that $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}^{-1} = \varphi_{\beta\alpha}$.
Still, the problems have not all gone away. It is possible for $\varphi_{12}\varphi_{23}\varphi_{31}x \neq x$, which would not be forbidden by the inverse requirement. It appears that thinking up specific rules to block off particular counterexamples will not be sufficient.

So, I would like to know what conditions I have to apply in the "inside view," if I want to guarantee that an atlas specified in that way is really a manifold. How can I do this?

Comment: You will have to require the transition condition $\varphi_{\alpha \beta}=\varphi_{\alpha \gamma} \circ \varphi_{\gamma\beta}$ and $\varphi_{\alpha \alpha}=id$. This, in particular, implies $\varphi_{\alpha\circ \beta}^{-1}=\varphi_{\beta\circ \alpha}$.

Comment: @PtF What about when $\varphi_{ac}$ and $\varphi_{cb}$ exist but $\varphi_{ab}$ does not? (For example if the $a$ part of the manifold and the $b$ part are disjoint).

Comment: Technically, with the cocycle condition $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}=\varphi_{\alpha\gamma}\circ\varphi_{\gamma\beta}$ one means to say the maps agree on the domain where they are all defined. If this is the empty set, than it automatically holds. Smoothness and the cocycle condition will not be enough,though: one must also require that the resulting space is second countable and Hausdorff.

Comment: I voted to close your question because it needs clarification. You do not properly explain what an "inside view atlas" should be. If the $V_\alpha$ are taken from an "ordinary atlas", then you do not have functions $\varphi_{\alpha\beta} : V_\alpha \rightarrow V_\beta$. The transition functions live on open subsets of $V_\alpha, V_\beta$.

Comment: @PaulFrost That's a good point, but I would argue that the goal of this question is to learn how to specify the inside view! I don't know how to specify it. However I have edited the question to take your note in to account.